# Responsive elements don't stack right between 768 and 785 pixels

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

I need another set of eyes on this, so thanks for your time. I've got a commerce template based on Zurb Foundation which moves around a couple of elements using jQuery based on the width of the page. I've hit a hitch, probably due to ignorance of the underlying math, and I could use a hand.

[Here's the static template](http://dev.imperativeideas.com/metrappleous/theme.php)

The relevant jQuery is a function that fires on doc ready and on resize:

```
function organize() {
    var welcome = $('#welcome').remove();
    var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    var innerwidth = $('body').innerWidth();

    // Move the Welcome DIV - we ALWAYS do this
    welcome.appendTo('#content-wrap');

    // If we're mobile, let's move a few things around
    if( innerwidth < 768 ) {
        if (!sidebar.hasClass('mobile')) {
            var sidecut = sidebar.addClass('mobile').detach();
            sidecut.prependTo('#content-wrap')
        }
    }
    // If we've gone bigger, put things back where we found them
    if( innerwidth >= 768) {
        if (sidebar.hasClass('mobile')) {
            var sidefix = sidebar.removeClass('mobile').detach();
            sidefix.insertAfter('#primary');

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, using the 768px break point I'm moving the sidebar to the top instead of the bottom, where it would otherwise stack based on source order. I've tried document.width as well but innerWidth seems to give an extra pixel of tolerance. Although the break is at 768, I have CSS issues all the way up to 785, at which point everything resolves itself.

The relevant bits of CSS are here (SCSS format)

```
// Shop Menu
#shopmenu {
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 80px 0;
    padding: 0;
    @include display;
    li {
      background: $level-4;
      font-size:20px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid $level-3;
      &:first-child {
        padding: 0 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
      }
      &:last-child {border-bottom: none;}
      a {
        color: rgb(25,25,25);
        padding: 0 20px;
        &:hover {
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
      }
      ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        ul {
          padding-left: 25px;
          ul {
            padding-left: 30px;
            ul {
              padding-left: 35px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      li {
        background: $level-4;
        font-size:17px;
        &:first-child {
          padding: 0;
          font-size: 20px;
        }
        a {
          padding: 0 30px;
          font-size: 16px;
        }
        li {
          border: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm not doing much with that breakpoint in CSS, other than adjusting some padding, which isn't the issue (it persists without that part in there). That includes having checked the additional breakpoints for #content-wrap ul.products li, where I change the % width to justify the LI [based on this technique](http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/). Again, even if I go to an unstyled list, the problem persists.

Here's hoping someone spots my derp by the time I wake up in 4 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking at this. Eventually, I managed to find the solution by removing all of the jQuery used to move element blocks around and following their directions manually. It was then that I remembered the Foundation push/pull classes actually trigger their own JS based source ordering, which was conflicting with my additional directions.

I ended up refactoring the script (needed anyhow) to put the "mobile" class on the body, then from there I gave instructions to not only move the items appropriately, but also to addClass() or removeClass() the push/pull Foundation commands.

```
// We need a function to add and remove the mobile class based on width
function setmobile() {
    thewidth = $(document).width(); // refresh this value when setting anew
    if (thewidth < 768) {
        thebody.addClass('mobile');
    } else {
        thebody.removeClass('mobile');
    }
}


// The source order is not the display order, let's play
function organize() {
    // Move the Welcome DIV - we ALWAYS do this
    var welcome = $('#welcome').remove();
    welcome.appendTo('#content-wrap');

    // If we're mobile, let's move a few things around
    if (!thebody.hasClass('mobile')) {
        var sidemain = sidebar.detach();
        sidemain.insertAfter('#primary');
        sidebar.addClass('pull-9');
        primary.addClass('push-3');
    }

    // If we've gone bigger, put things back where we found them
    if (thebody.hasClass('mobile')) {
        var sidemobile = sidebar.detach();
        sidemobile.insertAfter('#navwrap');
        sidebar.removeClass('pull-9');
        primary.removeClass('push-3');
    }
}
```

After that it was a simple matter to run setmobile() and organize() on page ready, plus through a debounce script on resize.

With .push-3 and .pull-9 removed in mobile but added in desktop mode, the whole thing worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution is adding `float:left;` to the `<li>` elements instead of `display:inline-block;`

The problem using `display:inline-block` is the spaces added between the elements, this property adds 4 px space between the elements.

Comment: Thanks Ppollono, have a + for being helpful. In this case, however, I was using inline-block, along with a 0 height 100% width element, in order to trigger CSS text-align: justify; property on the line items. You can read about that here: http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this post, it opens up my mind about not using float and stop doing calculations with margins

Comment: Happy to share. You will find that Foundation's block grid works on almost the exact same principle: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html